# Tabs directive with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am creating an Angular tabs directive which would be applied as follows:

```
<div id="tabs-with-directive" data-tabs>      
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" data-tabs-link="1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-tabs-link="2">Two</a></li>
  </ul>            
  <div class="panes">
    <div data-tabs-pane="1" class="pane active">One</div>
    <div data-tabs-pane="2" class="pane">Two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So clicking on One would show pane one, on two would show pane two, ...

I created a working [Plunker example without using a directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/EqKuRfwnKi9j4IJMCrhh?p=preview)

And I have a [Plunker example using the directive I am trying to build](http://plnkr.co/edit/0gMuZ401yk7O99lbXNgE?p=preview):

```
angular.module("app", [tabs]);   

(function(angular) {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('tabs', []);

  angular.module('tabs')
    .directive('tabs', tabsDirective);

  function tabsDirective() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: tabsController
    };
  }

  function tabsController($scope) {

    $scope.tabs = [];

    this.addTab = function (tab) {
        $scope.tabs.push(tab);
    };

    this.isTabActive = function (link) {
      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.tabs.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.tabs[i].link == link)
          return $scope.tabs[i].active;
      }
      return false;
    };

    this.setTabToActive = function (link) {
      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.tabs.length; i++) 
        $scope.tabs[i].active = $scope.tabs[i].link == link;
    };        

  }

  tabsController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  angular.module('tabs')
    .directive('tabsLink', tabsLinkDirective);

  function tabsLinkDirective() {
    return {
        scope: false,
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^tabs',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {

          var tab = { link: attributes.link, active: "false" };
          controller.addTab(tab);

          element.bind('click', function () {
            controller.setTabToActive(attributes.link);
          });

          scope.$watch('tabs', function () {
            element.toggleClass('active', controller.isTabActive(attributes.link));
          });

        }
    };
  }

  angular.module('tabs')
    .directive('tabsPane', tabsPaneDirective);

  function tabsPaneDirective() {
    return {
        scope: false,
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^tabs',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {

            scope.$watch('tabs', function () {
              element.toggleClass('active', controller.isTabActive(attributes.pane));
            });

        }
    };
  }

})(angular);
```

Unfortunately this is not working and I cannot find what I am doing wrong.

Could someone, please, help me out?

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `$watch` compares for reference equality. Since you are modifying the objects in the array the array reference will remain the same and the watch listener will not fire.

To watch for modifications to the objects in the array you need to pass `true` as the third argument:

```
scope.$watch('tabs', function() {
  element.toggleClass('active', controller.isTabActive(tab.link));
}, true);
```

---

The following:

```
attributes.link
```

Should in all places be replaced with the following:

```
attributes.tabsLink
```

And the following:

```
attributes.pane
```

Should be replaced with:

```
attributes.tabsPane
```

---

I assume you want one of the tabs to start as active.

The following that you have will not work:

```
class="pane active"
```

Since none of the tab models have `active` set to `true`, the following code will just strip the `active` class away:

```
scope.$watch('tabs', function() {
  element.toggleClass('active', controller.isTabActive(attributes.tabsPane));
}, true);
```

If you want the `active` class to dictate if the tab should start as active you could add something like this:

```
if (element.hasClass('active')) {
  controller.setTabToActive(attributes.tabsPane);
}
```

Note that this doesn't prevent more than one tab from starting as active, nor does it set one to active if none has the class.

---

I highly recommend changing:

```
active: "false"
```

To:

```
active: false
```

And to use strict equality instead (`===` instead of `==`)

---

`element.on` is not an AngularJS function and will not trigger the digest loop for you - which means the data bindings will not be updated in the UI.

You will need to do it manually:

```
element.bind('click', function() {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    controller.setTabToActive(tab.link);
  });
});
```

---

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/9nskxIR0DHaDuAEG9CfX?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, completely missed your answer ... It is working great. Thank you for your help. I just marked as answer.